# Is the area of an inscribed shape less-than-or-equal-to that of the circumscribed shape *by definition*? Or is work needed to prove this?

Tags: geometry

This fact is obvious, but I want to make sure I'm being fully rigorous.

Say that I have a circle of radius $1$ inscribed in a square of side length $2$. Surely the area of the circle is strictly less than the area of the square --  it's obvious from the picture -- but is this a definition of "inscribed"? Does the definition only give me that the area of the inscribed shape is less than or equal to the circumscribed shape, and further work is needed to show the inequality is strict?

I'm trying to figure out which facts I can take as definitional and which require proof.

Comment: Area being strictly less doesn't imply inscribing, and unless we are talking about "nice" shapes, inscribed shapes don't necessarily have less area than the object they are inscribed in.

Comment: Do you have a definition of "inscribed" that you are working with?